# What is the probability of 100 students giving 50 scores of 3, 35 scores of 2, and 15 scores of 1?

Tags: probability

A class of 100 students is asked to rate how much they enjoyed a school activity from 1 to 3.

How can we calculate the probability that the scores are exactly 50 of rating=3, 35 of rating=2, and 15 of rating=1?

In addition, suppose that all ratings are equally as likely.

I have already calculated that the total number of possible combinations of ratings is C(102, 2) = 5151.

Comment: To determine the probability of such outcomes we need to define a probability distribution.  Perhaps you have in mind that a student is equally likely to give a rating of $1,2$ or $3$, but you don't say as much.

Comment: Depends on how good the school activity was.

Comment: Fair enough, I added that all ratings have equal probability.

Comment: The 5151 possible combinations of ratings that you allude to, counted by stars and bars, are **not** equally likely to have occurred.  Do not fall into the trap of using stars-and-bars with probability.  Easily nine times out of ten it is blatantly incorrect to do so.

Comment: The answer you are looking for is the [Multinomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#:~:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20the%20multinomial,sided%20die%20rolled%20n%20times.), the big brother to the binomial distribution allowing more than just two possible outcomes.  The probability you are after here is going to be $\binom{100}{50,35,15}\frac{1}{3^{100}}$

Comment: I just want to say, this problem is a terrible way to teach probability, because it takes a poll result and tries to understand it as a 100% uniform random selection by the participants. In general, if we poll $100$ people randomly chosen out of a larger population, we are *learning* something about the percentage probabilities that people will make each choice. In particular, it is highly unlikely the probabilities of each rating here are equal. Surveys and polls would be useless if the probability of each answer was equally likely.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews On the one hand, I agree with you about the significance of polling data.  On the other hand, I consider the analysis contained in the comments of J Moravitz as very valuable.  If I was writing a probability book, I would include this problem but simultaneously include your thoughts, so that the probability student could get the *best of both worlds*.

Comment: On the other hand, this probability can be also viewed as an evident against a null hypothesis of $p_1 = p_2 = p_3 = 1/3$. The small probability of have more "extreme" statistics means a low p-value and that suggest to reject the null hypothesis.